# webpack/tsconfig settup when export tsx and import in ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, cypress, tsconfig

I have one question about how I can use the export const from `tsx` file in `ts` file. After setting up the webpack and tsconfig. I notice that the cypress pretty much crashes when I use the const from `tsx` file in `ts` file. However, if I use the const from `ts` under the same path with `tsx` in the same `ts` file. I have no error and no problem to run it. something I did wrong?

```
// /app/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["./src/*"],
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

// /app/cypress/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": false,
    "types": ["cypress", "chai"]
  }
}

// /app/cypress/webpack.cypress.config.js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@types': path.resolve(__dirname, './types'),
      '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    },
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};


// /app/cypress/test.spec.ts
import {selectorModelTsx} from '@src/modelTsx';
import {selectorModelTs} from '@src/modelTs';

describe('test for import const from tsx to ts', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        //  TypeError: err.replace is not a function
        //   at cleanseError (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.4.1_f3cb6a2e00e6948ca1e63d4e51ac8233/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:226:16)
        //   at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        //   at handle (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.4.1_f3cb6a2e00e6948ca1e63d4e51ac8233/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:137:22)
        // console.log(selectorModelTsx) failed with the error
        console.log(selectorModelTs) // no error
    });
});
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a 'test' regex for the babel-loader?

Comment: From webpack? Hm not sure but it doesn't seem solve after I add it up

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `cypress/tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "files": [
    "../cypress/**/*.ts",  /** or just **/*.ts */
    "../cypress.config.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": ["cypress"]
  }
}
```